With React query : Query sent twice when setStart and setSearch (useState) change simultaneously. (search and start are query params)
The problem is : if i change start and search in the same time, two queries are sent, but I just want one.
const [start, setStart] = useState(0);
const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

const { data: usersData, error: usersError, isLoading: usersIsLoading, isError: usersIsError } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['users', start, search],
    queryFn: () => getUsers(start, search)
});

The solution I found is to use a debounce function :
const [start, setStart] = useState(0);
const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

const debouncedStart = useValueDebounce(start, 500);
const debouncedSearch = useValueDebounce(search, 500);

function useValueDebounce(value, delay) {
    const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = setTimeout(() => {
            setDebouncedValue(value);
        }, delay);

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(handler);
        };
    }, [value, delay]);

    return debouncedValue;
}

const { data: usersData, error: usersError, isLoading: usersIsLoading, isError: usersIsError } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['users', debouncedStart, debouncedSearch],
        queryFn: () => getUsers(limit, debouncedStart, debouncedSearch)
    });

Is there a better way to do that ?

Are start and search being updated on the same re-render cycle, or on different ones?  The problem may be in how they're being updated, not in how this code responds to those updates.
